# Can I use Google Maps API (Places API) in my iPhone app to find locations near me?

Tags: iphone, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

I have a couple of questions regarding using Google maps API, especially the Places API in my iPhone application.

1. Can I use Places API in my iPhone app and still release the app as a paid app? Could I release my app as free if I am unable to use these APIs in a paid app?
2. Is there an example for figuring out store locations around user's current location using Places API? For example if the user types "Groceries" in the app, I would like to show all the Store that sell groceries near the user's location.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Taken from their terms and conditions:

> If your Maps API Implementation is
>   deployed internally or you are
>   charging for use of your Maps API
>   Implementation, please contact the
>   [Google Maps API Premier sales
>   team](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/bin/request.py?contact_type=gme&utm_campaign=en-us-codeterms) for more information.

2) Location is a required parameter in any search request:

> http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use Google Map API in paid apps according to the term of use 9.1.1-(a) and 9.1.2-(b). The terms of service can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms :
   (b) Mobile Applications. The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access) does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.
2. Examples can be found at https://developers.google.com/places/ and https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/