# iPhone app: how to implement Google Places Api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, google-maps-api-3

In iPhone App I want to integrate Google Places Api.

Is there any sample project or tutorial which can help me in implementing it?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864682/how-use-google-api-in-iphone-to-query-hotels-around-my-place

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use Google Maps API (Places API) in my iPhone app to find locations near me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993864/can-i-use-google-maps-api-places-api-in-my-iphone-app-to-find-locations-near-m)

Comment: Duplicate of the question in the accepted answer: [how use google api in iphone to query hotels around my place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864682/how-use-google-api-in-iphone-to-query-hotels-around-my-place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could implement google Place api from [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864682/how-use-google-api-in-iphone-to-query-hotels-around-my-place)

using the url I could get the response and Using JSON parsing I filtered the data as per my requirements

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there are one major good tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit). It answers all the question

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge. You will have to create the call yourself. You might want to use Foursquare API (There's a lot of Foursquare Framework for iOS out there).

If you really want to use Google Places API, you will probably be better off using your own implementation (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535361/google-places-api-in-ios-application) for some links related to the API) with NSURLConnections.

Answer (score -1):

most of the sample above is call http to google server to get places in the iphone app , 
but it has potential risk since the google server key is easy to be seen by others.

besides,ip restrict is no help in this example.

so the proper way is to pass the parameter to your own server and then call google server at your own server.